# Python iterative subtraction of a list

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have an array of n values and I want to subtract n different values to each of them for m times (every time you subtract from the previous result).

I want to save the entire matrix.

I tried with two nested for loops but I didn't manage to do it and I couldn't find any post strictly related...

data = https://www.dropbox.com/s/anhyqq9f7h75qee/trace1.dat?dl=0

values_to_subtract = (data - k)/m

k = constant value

**example:**

```
x = np.array([x1,x2,x3])

m = 3

dx = (x-k)/m
```

I want to decrease every element of x of its own calculated amount *dx* and I want to do it 3 times to get this matrix:

[Target Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQQRp.png)

Thanks a lot

Comment: post the actual array and expected final result

Comment: Edit the question to show a small worked example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward to do using [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> dx = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
>>> dx
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
>>> dx * np.arange(4)
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 4, 6],
       [0, 3, 6, 9]])
>>> x = np.array([[10], [10], [10]])
>>> x - dx * np.arange(4)
array([[10,  9,  8,  7],
       [10,  8,  6,  4],
       [10,  7,  4,  1]])
```

What broadcasting does, generally, if your arrays are of compatible shapes, is apply operations along all axes in a nice way. So at this step:

```
>>> dx * np.arange(4)
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 4, 6],
       [0, 3, 6, 9]])
```

numpy is taking the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product), viz.:

```
[1]                  [0  1*1  2*1  3*1]
[2]  *  [0 1 2 3]  = [0  1*2  2*2  3*2]
[3]                  [0  1*3  2*3  3*3]
```

and this gives all the values you want to subtract from `x`. Broadcasting `x - dx * np.arange(4)` takes the column vector `x` and broadcasts it to the same shape as the outer product (copying the values at each column) so that this final operation looks like

```
[10  10  10  10]     [0  1*1  2*1  3*1]
[10  10  10  10]  -  [0  1*2  2*2  3*2]
[10  10  10  10]     [0  1*3  2*3  3*3]
```

which is equal to, as is your LaTeX equation:

```
[x1  x1-dx  x1-2dx  x1-3dx]
[x2  x2-dx  x2-2dx  x2-3dx]
[x3  x3-dx  x3-2dx  x3-3dx]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexander... but for some reason my code (the same of yours) it doesn't work because it says that operands could not be broadcast together with different shapes. It's the outer product which doesn't work, I guess. Consider that my data (my 'x') are loaded as a txt file using np.loadtxt...

Comment: Yours is probably not the same shape as mine. Note that my `x` is shape (3,1). What's yours?

Comment: if I check it with np.shape it says (10136,)

Comment: Oops, sorry---the `x` shape like yours is fine (mine here is (3,)) but the `dx` shape in yours is what's wrong. It needs to be a column vector. If it's also a row vector like (n,) then just reshape it into a column vector with `dx = dx.reshape((len(dx), 1))`, then it should be `(n,1)`.

Comment: It  works now, thank you!!